# How to fix 'TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'part'' error in python

Tags: python, python-docx

The console keeps telling me this, saying there is a parameter missing.

```
"D:\Program Files (x86)\Python\python.exe" D:/workspace/Glossary_Builder_Python/main.py
Please input the file path
C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Allergies.docx
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/workspace/Glossary_Builder_Python/main.py", line 102, in <module>
    main(sys.argv)
  File "D:/workspace/Glossary_Builder_Python/main.py", line 98, in main
    extractWdFrmDocx(filepath)
  File "D:/workspace/Glossary_Builder_Python/main.py", line 18, in extractWdFrmDocx
    document = Document(file)
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'part'
```

I am trying to extract some highlighted(in yellow) text from a docx file, using python-docx and python 3.7.
When I go into Document func, the `__init__` looks like this:

```
def __init__(self, element, part):
    super(Document, self).__init__(element)
    self._part = part
    self.__body = None
```

so here, what is 'part' for?

Below is the extracting function and main function:

```
def extractWdFrmDocx(filepath):
    # self.filepath = filepath
    document = Document(filepath)
    for para in document.paragraphs:
        for run in para.runs:
            if run.font.highlight_color == WD_COLOR_INDEX.YELLOW:
                keyText.append(run.text)
    print(keyText)


def main(argv):
    print("Please input the file path")
    filepath = input()
    extractWdFrmDocx(filepath)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv)
```

Comment: Well like the error says, your Document init expects an argument, `part`, that you're not supplying; you're only passing a single argument, which is taken as the `element` argument. You need to pass both.

Comment: `so here, what is 'part' for?` - Did you write that class? If not its documentation should describe it - if not you will have to look further into the class to figure out *what it is for*.

Answer (score 2):

Probably you imported `Document` from `docx.document`. You are not supposed to construct such a `Document` object directly. Instead a function for creating `Document` objects is provided as `docx.Document` which expects one argument, the way you are using it right now.

Therefore your code should be:

```
import docx

[...]

document = docx.Document(filepath)
```

[From documentation of python-docx:](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/document.html)

> **Document objects**
>
> class docx.document.Document
>
> [...]
>
> Not intended to be constructed directly. Use docx.Document() to open or create a document.

Comment: This can happen when you have `from docx.document import Document` instead of `from docx import Document`. The former is the actual document object you work with and the latter is the "factory" function that creates that for you by loading a specified file or loading the default built-in template file. You definitely want the latter.